# UWP Compatible package for System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap and System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, rendering, writeablebitmap

I have a WPF pdf viewer code. I'm trying to convert it into UWP. 
To render the pages of a pdf, WPF uses System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap. 
UWP compatible Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap doesn't contain all the functionalities 
as in wpf compatible package.
I can't find functions to replace the below methods.

```
WriteableBitmap renderTarget;
var bitmapFormat = GetBitmapFormat(renderTarget.Format);
renderTarget.Lock();
renderTarget.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(rectDest.left, rectDest.top, rectDest.width, rectDest.height));
renderTarget.Unlock();
```

**Does anyone know a workaround or new package which I can use to replace those methods( Format, Lock, AddDirtyRect, Unlock)?**

**The above package also should have a constructor that accepts following parameters.**

```
WriteableBitmap(int pixelWidth, int pixelHeight, double dpiX, double dpiY, PixelFormat pixelFormat, BitmapPalette palette);
```

Additionally, Need to replace System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats and use a UWP compatible one. UWP
compatible Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapPixelFormat does not contain all pixel formats such as 
Bgra32, Bgr32, Bgr24).

Comment: See the Remarks section on the [WriteableBitmap.PixelBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.pixelbuffer#Windows_UI_Xaml_Media_Imaging_WriteableBitmap_PixelBuffer) page.

Comment: Hi, If you need to render Pdf in UWP, you may need a new way to adopt `PdfDocument` and display it with `BitmapImage`. Here is the [complete example](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/PdfDocument)